# нужна помощь в написании решении и проверки задачи по Scala

Tags: scala

есть задача с условием, как ее решить и написать проверку?

Условие :  Данные массив целых чисел ‘nums’ и целое число ‘target’
Необходимо вернуть массив из двух чисел из массива ‘nums’ таких, что их сумма равна target
Если таких числе нет, то вернуть массив Array(-1,-1).
Условие1: 2 <= nums.length <= 10000; Условие: -2^31 <= nums(i) <= 2^31 - 1; Условие: -2^31 <= target <= 2^31 -1

```
Def twoSum(nums: Array[int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
Array.empty[Int]
}

assert(twoSum(Array(1,2,3),3).sorted.sameElements(Array(1,2)))
assert(twoSum(Array(1,2,3),5).sorted.sameElements(Array(2,3)))
assert(twoSum(Array(1,2,3),4).sorted.sameElements(Array(1,3)))
assert(twoSum(Array(1,2,3),6).sorted.sameElements(Array(-1,-1)))
assert(twoSum(Array(1,9,1),2).sorted.sameElements(Array(1,1)))
assert(twoSum(Array(1,9,1),10).sorted.sameElements(Array(1,9)))
assert(twoSum(Array.tabulate(1000)(! => i + 1),
9999 + 10000).sorted.sameElements(Array(9999,10000)))
assert(twoSum(Array.tabulate(10000)(I => i + 1), 10000 + 10001).sorted.sameElements(Array(-1,-1)))
}
```

Comment: def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
        for (i <- 0 until nums.length; j <- i + 1 until nums.length 
             if nums(i) + nums(j) == target) {
          Array(nums(i), nums(j))
        }
        Array(-1, -1)
      }

есть примерное решение, но как написать проверку?

Answer (score 1):

Примерное решение в вашем комментарии правильное, только нет теле цикла ключевого слова `return`:

```
def twoSum(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Array[Int] = {
  for (
    i <- nums.indices;
    j <- (i + 1) until nums.length if nums(i) + nums(j) == target
  ) return Array(nums(i), nums(j))

  Array(-1, -1)
}
```

Таким образом, функцию вернёт результат, как только найдёт первую подходящую пару. Если же не найдёт, то вернёт последнее выражение функции, то есть `Array(-1, -1)`.

По поводу проверок - зависит от выбранной вами библиотеки для написания проверок. Чаще всех мне попадалась https://www.scalatest.org/ . Приведённый вами пример проверок тоже вполне себе подходит.

Comment: мне условно не очень понятно, как написать код в IJ, чтобы программа запустилась. например какие числа подать, на сайт который вы скинули, чет совсем не понял. нам же нужно просто в проверке заменить функцию в условие с кодом, который вы подретактировали и ниже дописать assert и в принт лн подать 3 числа?

Comment: Что такое IJ? На каком сайте выполняете? Лучше прикрепите скриншот, не совсем понял что от вас требуется дописать по задаче

Comment: сейчас у меня есть условие, которое написано выше, есть решение, которое дописали вы. но в intelejii Idea я не могу собрать все вместе. я хочу,
чтоб я мог подставить нужны числа и программа заработала. Как мне этого добиться?

условно пример - условие - "выведите в консоль х n -раз". -  есть решение - def f(n: int) = for(i <- 1 to n) println(x)  - вот и в принтлн я впишу число н, которое мне надо и все заработает, а как это сделать здесь

Comment: Для Idea необходимо установить плагин Scala, он доступен в Marketplace. Затем создать проект Scala (как правило, на sbt). В самом проекте создать файл с объектом `object Main extends App { println("Hello, World!" }` . Здесь уже в теле этого объекта и есть точка входа, как в Java например `public static void main`. Если проект на Scala 3, то там вообще достаточно навесить на функцию аннотацию @main: `@main def main: Unit = { println("Hello, World!") }`. А дальше уже разрабатываете программу. Для чтения с клавиатуры в консоле можно юзать `val x = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()`.

Comment: Более подробно здесь: https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started/intellij-track/getting-started-with-scala-in-intellij.html

Comment: это все есть, я имею ввиду, что у меня есть объект (с которого начинается проект в скала), который принимает на себя строку, далее фигурные скобочки и вот что дальше в какой последовательности нужно сделать,чтобы заработала проверка,сейчас пришлю пример скриншотом

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16cTf0CIRK0ONn7AQqoEAC0DJFag89Z59?usp=sharing 

ссылка на скриншот, вот как сделать там проверку и полностью рабочую программу?

Comment: Выглядит так, что нужно просто подставить реализацию функции `twoSum`, запустить программу и если она не упала с ошибками, тогда значит реализация верная. Проверки в проекте уже готовые. Лучше уточните у кураторов вашего курса.

Comment: это задание из книги и оно последнее, но я уже голову сломал с проверкой? есть вариант как подставить можно?пример может быть?

Comment: Просто в 4 строчке заместо `Array.empty[Int]` подставляешь свою реализацию. Запускаешь `main`, если упало с ошибкой - значит решение не верное, иначе "Красавчик!")

Comment: в скриншоты добавил файл, при разных раскладах горит красным и значит, что не выполнится, но ошибка то вроде не в решении...

Comment: хотя в тестовом (добавил еще один скриншот) варианте , функция работает

Comment: Не уж то не очевидно, что в Скала нет ключевого слова `Def`?

Comment: Def - объявление функции, где конкретная ошибка в сборке проверки? почему не компилируется?

Comment: Скала придирчивая к регистру, как большинство языков. То есть `Def` не тоже самое, что `def`.

Comment: а, спасибо за уточнение, но при любом раскладе тогда инт горит красным( добавил скриншот) следовательно программа не скомпилируется и i в assert тоже красная

Comment: Потому что опять же, Скала придирчив к регистру и такого ключевого слова, как `int` нету, есть `Int`. Там где `i` горит красным тоже проблема, что такой переменной в данном окружении не определено, там есть `I` и `!` (вообще бесовщина). Должно быть, ты просто скопировал фрагмент из pdf книжки, вот и кракозябра, вместо необходимого. В обоих случаях должна быть лямбда `i => i + 1`.

Comment: Также, чтобы сократить алгоритмическую сложность с О(N^2) до O(N), я бы посмотрел решение проблемы 2Sum на литкоде, и попытался бы реализовать его на Scala.